# Golang - How to overcome Scan() buffer limit from bufio?

Tags: go, io, buffer

I am using the `bufio` scanner's `.Scan()` method to read text file lines. However when I reach a certain size in the file lines, the scanner no longer allows me to read, it just returns an empty line.

How should I configure the buffer to take in larger amounts of data?

`bigfile.txt` is just a file with many integers in a line separated by a space. For example, 40000 integers in one line. (note that it works for file lines of 10000 integers and less, but not 40000 for example)

> 234 544 765 45 34 67 67 87 98 43 [... n = 40000 ]

```
func main() {
    readInputFile("bigfile.txt")
}

func readInputFile(name string) {
    inFile, _ := os.Open(name)
    defer inFile.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inFile)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Printf(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: After your `for` loop add a call to `scanner.Err()` and see what it gives you back. Maybe there's something useful there? https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Err

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Buffer) and corresponding [source code](https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan.go), by default `Scanner` uses internal buffer in which the capacity is 64K. In your case, the internal buffer is not sufficient for storing 40000 integers. Set the buffer to be used by scanner **before** calling `Scan`, i.e.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(inFile)

//adjust the capacity to your need (max characters in line)
const maxCapacity = 512*1024  
buf := make([]byte, maxCapacity)
scanner.Buffer(buf, maxCapacity)
```

Comment: why buffer size set to 512*1024?

Comment: Simply as an example. The actual capacity will depend on your specific input.

Answer (score 3):

A code to use dynamic buffer size. Get the file size and use it in the scanner

```
info, infoErr := file.Stat()
var maxSize int
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
maxSize = int(info.Size())
buffer := make([]byte, 0, maxSize)
scanner.Buffer(buffer, maxSize)
```

For JSON add a few more bytes
maxSize = maxSize + 1
or
maxSize = maxSize + 10

Comment: Why "For JSON add a few more bytes"? And, why "+1" or "+10"... how would you decide?

Comment: what effect does this have on resource usage by the program? Does a larger scanner buffer size cause more memory to be used?